# Reading a directory with PHP on GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm trying to read a directory with php's scandir on Google App Engine. The files within the folder 'img' are definitely reachable, but I am trying to get a list of all files in the folder.
What's wrong?

All files are apparently uploaded correctly, so app.yaml should be fine.
Is it a PHP error or a GAE restriction?

This is my main php-script, run when accessing my site's /:

```
   <?php

    $dir = 'img';
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        //this code is never reached:
        echo "directory exists :-)";
        $filenames = scandir($dir, 0);
        print_r($filesnames);
    } else {
        echo "No such directory";
    }

    // this works:
    echo "<div>
        <img src=\"/img/example.png\">
    </div>";

    // this works:
    $files1 = scandir(getcwd());
    print_r($files1);

    ?>
```

opendir($dir) doesnt help either.

Here's my app.yaml:

```
application: mypage
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:

# image files
- url: /img/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: img/\1
  upload: img/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))

- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.php

# this is probably redundant:
- url: /img
  static_dir: img
```

**EDIT:**
Adding this line to the image files section (not necessarily the img folder) solved the problem:
  application_readable: true

Comment: Are the files in the `img` dir served using a `static_dir` handler in a `.yaml` file?

Comment: yes (I edited the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Static_directory_handlers):

> **application_readable**
>
> Optional. By default, files declared in static file handlers are
>   uploaded as static data and are only served to end users, they cannot
>   be read by an application. If this field is set to true, the files are
>   also uploaded as code data so your application can read them. Both
>   uploads are charged against your code and static data storage resource
>   quotas.

Try adding the `application_readable` flag to the `img` handler. I'm not 100% sure if the flag will also cover the `img` dir itself in addition to its content. It's worth a try.